# iOS - Debug my Framework in my App XCode project

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods, podspec

I have created an iOS Framework "MySDK" which exposes API to my App "MyApp" to send an Alert to my backend. I'd like to walk through the Alert sending code from XCode in debugger. MySDK and MyApp have their own workspaces.

I build my SDK in XCode, and then I build my App with Cocoapods (do a pod install to get the correct versions of all libraries, followed by building manually in XCode) The Podfile for MyApp references the framework as shown.

What is the best/most elegant/non-intrusive way to create a symbolicated/debug version of MySDK and then build my App with it? The end goal is to be able to walk through any part of MyApp or MySDK in one XCode session.

[image]

Comment: You should use the path in the pod file to point to your local MySDK project folder. Then, cocoa pods will set it as a development pod and you can step  code directly from my app

Comment: Thanks Paulw11. I tried that but still no debug symbols/step into available.

Comment: Typo - I means still “no info available”  - how do you build the framework so that when you point the possible to the local version of the Library it has the debug symbols and you can step into it with the Xcode debugger?

Comment: When you integrate a development pod you should have the source rather than just a framework in your project.

Comment: Do you mean something like this?

Comment: Pod MySDK, :path => ‘~/Documents/MySDK’

Comment: How do I get the " source rather than just a framework in my project"?
MyApp and MySDK are two separate Workspaces and GitHub Repos. Do I need to write a script to include MySDK in MyApp's Workspace. Is there an example of how to do this/best practices somewhere that you know of?